# An Application of Helly Theorem

Tags: discrete-geometry

Let $X$ be a compact subset of $R^n$. Prove that if any $≤ n + 1$ points of $X$ can be covered by a unit ball not containing the origin then the whole $X$ can be covered by a unit ball not containing the origin.

Note: If we remove the condition that unit ball not containing the origin, then the solution is just a simple use of Helly theorem. To see this,

for each $x\in X$, put $A_{x}=\{b\in\mathbb{R}^n : x\in b+B_n(0,1)\}$, where here $B_n(0,1)$ is the unit closed ball at origin. It is easy to see that $A_x$ is convex and compact. Indeed, By the assumption, any $\leq n+1$ of them has non-empty intersection. Now, by using Helly theorem for family of compact convex sets, we have $\bigcap_{x\in X}A_X\neq\emptyset$. Now, for any $r\in\bigcap_{x\in X}A_X\neq\emptyset$, we have $X\subseteq r+B_n(0,1)$.

Comment: Is this homework?  Even if it is not, problems that are worded imperatively ("Prove that …") tend not to be received well on MO.

Comment: Hint 1: All points lie in some open half-space with the boundary plane through the origin. Hint 2: Inversion is your friend. Hint 3: No, not with respect to the origin!!! Think better! ;-)

Comment: @fedja Thank you very much for the hints. I have just verified the first hint. But I couldn't understand how should I use the other ones! could you explain more!

Comment: Inversion maps balls not containing the inversion center to balls.